# Power BI matrix - how to add two fields to "values" to have the totals per line, but only the details of one of them appear in columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to "untoggle" this breakdown by columns for a specific field ?

I want what I highlighted in green to be show, but not what is highlighted in red.

[My matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APkA6.png)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcOTQcMFmhc